# Encryption strategy for access to more than one account

Tags: encryption

In my app I give users the ability to store data and share it with specific other users. We are going to add a layer of security by encrypting the data stored and using a users specific public key to decrypt and view the data. What is the best way to enable those other users with access to decrypt and view the data? Use the public key to get a shared cipher perhaps? I'm not sure on how to approach this :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using a user-specific key is **not** the correct way to go if you want to share some but not all files. Instead, you'd want a file-specific key.

In turn, you encrypt this file key with the public key of the owner. If the owner wants to share the file, he decrypts the file key with his private key and re-encrypts it with the public key of the person he wants to share the file with.

This means you use symmetric key cryptography for the files, and asymmetric key cryptography for the key management.

Comment: Ah, so if I understand correctly I need to create copies of the file-specific keys for every user that has access. That makes sense...

Comment: Yes but these can be stored together in a single metadata fragment, Keys are small.